# Spring webflux - How to protect RESTful private resources?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

HI I have a springboot webflux app with spring boot security. I authenticate using basic auth. I have an endpoint that provides private resource `/users/{userId}/notifications` and I want to make sure that only users which is authenticated can access the specific private resource.

For example I authenticate as a user with id: 3

I CAN access: `/users/3/notifications`

I CANNOT access: `/users/1/notifications`

Here is my sample code using @PreAuthorize but it's not working at all

```
    @PostMapping("/users/{userId}/notifications")
    // @Secured(value = ["userid"]) - also doesn't work
    @PreAuthorize("#userId == principal.id")
    fun addEmailNotification(@RequestBody emailNotificationCreationForm: @Valid EmailNotificationCreationForm): Mono<ResponseEntity<EmailNotificationCreationResponse>> {
//        log.info("Adding email notification {}", emailNotificationCreationForm)
        return Mono
                .just(emailNotificationCreationForm)
                .doOnNext { println(it) }
                .flatMap { Mono.just(EmailNotificationSetting("aa","bb")) }
                .map { EmailNotificationCreationResponse(true, 201, it) }
                .map { ResponseEntityUtils.toResponseEntity(it, HttpStatus.CREATED) }
    }
```

Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
internal open class SecurityConfig(private val userService: UserService) {

    companion object {
        private val AUTH_WHITELIST = arrayOf("/actuator/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/ui", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**")
    }

    @Bean
    open fun securityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, REGISTRATION_REQUESTS_ENDPOINT).permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, AUTH_ENDPOINT).permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(*AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, Endpoints.forSecurity(REGISTRATION_REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS_ENDPOINT)).permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, Endpoints.forSecurity(REGISTRATION_REQUEST_CONFIRMATION_ENDPOINT)).permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .build()
    }
```

Comment: if user 1 and user 3 are different users, you instead just do a GET to /users/notifications and then in your method you check who the currently logged in user that made the request is and get that specific persons notifications.

Comment: yep I know I can do it like that but I don't want to. I need to have an endpoint like /users/{id}/notifications

Comment: imho that is bad practice, well good luck!

Comment: It looks like you are missing the `@PathVariable String userId` as a controller parameter